# Getting Cannot read property 'Email' of undefined using meteor and simple-schema

Tags: meteor, simpl-schema

How can I get Email property using `simpl-schema`? I'm getting undefined message when using calling Email property. Not sure if anything changed because the implementation is according to the docs.

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import SimpleSchema from "simpl-schema";
import { Accounts } from "meteor/accounts-base";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup

  Accounts.validateNewUser(user => {
    const email = user.emails[0].address;

    try {
      new SimpleSchema({
        email: {
          type: String,
          regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
        }
      }).validate({ email });
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(400, e.message);
    }

    return true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you having an issue with this line: const email = user.emails[0].address; , or the schema validation?

Comment: Just reproduced with a fresh install and mine is running fine. Which `simpl-schema` version are you using?

Comment: @Jankapunkt, I'm using 1.5.0.